# Why is my avatar failing to display on 10/27/2016?

Tags: discussion

My avatar failed to load on a lot of SE sites including this one.

Why?

Comment: Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286378/i-stack-imgur-com-has-an-expired-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 4):

**Imgur SSL Certificates are failing**

There is an issue with Imgur that displays many of the images on SE.

SE Admins are currently working with Imgur to resolve this issue.

Imgur uses these SSL certificates to encrypt data between Imgur and it's end users.  SSL uses TCP port 443 whereas standard web communication that is un-encrypted uses TCP port 80.

You will know when the issue is resolved when images and avatars begin to function again.